# How to have procmail start ftp server

Tags: procmail

I am trying to have procmail start proftpd when it recieves a mail with a subject string of "Ftp Up" ...

Currently I have this

```
:0:
* ^From:.mymail@mailserver.com
* ^Subject:.^Ftp()+Up
| /etc/init.d/proftpd start
```

But this is not working ...

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex has a number of weird errors.  It's impossible for `^Subject:^Ftp` to match if the `Subject:` header is well-formed because `Ftp` could never match at beginning of line (well, unless the `Subject:` header is immediately followed by a `Ftp:` header, which doesn't exist, so that's fairly unlikely to be what you want) and it's unclear what you hope to accomplish by repeating an empty group̣.

Try this instead:

```
:0   # Notice absence of second colon
* ^From.*mymail@mailserver\.com
* ^Subject:[    ]*Ftp Up$
| sudo /etc/init.d/proftpd start
```

The whitespace in the square brackets are a space and a tab.  The square brackets form a character class and the asterisk repeats the class zero or more times, so this matches arbitrary runs of horizontal whitespace.

I imagine you don't have privileges to start system services from your email account (if you do, change it!) so I added a `sudo` as well.  You will need to set up appropriate `sudo` privileges for your account to run this command without a password.

The gratuituous lock file is a FAQ; see http://porkmail.org/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#locking

Comment: That answer was absolutely perfect, and I have learned a few things. Thank you so much. I appreciate it. Danny.